# Covariance & Contravariance with List vs IEnumerable

Tags: .net, covariance

So, let's say I have:

```
Public Interface ISomeInterface

End Interface

Public Class SomeClass
  Implements ISomeInterface

End Class
```

If I have `MyList` as `List(Of SomeClass)`, I cannot directly set a `List(Of ISomeInterface) = MyList`.  However, I can Set an `IEnumerable(Of ISomeInterface) = MyList`.

With my understanding of Covariance I thought that it should work list to list since `List(Of T)` implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`.  Clearly, I am missing something.

Why does it work that way?  Specifically why Can't I do something like:

```
Dim Animals As new List(Of Animal)
Dim Cats As List(Of IAnimal) = Animals
```

Where Animal implements the IAnimal Interface.  But I can do:

```
Dim Animals As New List(Of Animal)
Dim Cats As IEnumerable(Of IAnimal) = Animals
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/

Comment: I have read several articles, none of which have helped me answer this specific instance.  Can you point out the specific article or portion of it that covers why I can go directly from a list of the specific type to a list of the interface?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/26/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-interface-variance.aspx

Comment: That isn't really covering the specific question I have.  I want to know why this fails:  List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
List<IAnimal> Cats = Animal;  but this works:  List<animal> Animals = new List<animal>();
IEnumerable<IAnimal> Cats = Animals;

Comment: Have you looked at the MSDN documentation for `IEnumerable<T>`? Did you notice that the type parameter is defined as an `out` parameter only? That's why.

Comment: I'm slow but I got it.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recall seeing a lot of information around this issue on the web previously, so I'm not sure that my answer will really add anything new, but I'll try.

If you're using .NET 4, then notice that the definition of IEnumerable(Of T) is actually IEnumerable(Of Out T).  The new Out keyword has been introduced in version 4, which indicates the covariance of this interface.  The List(Of T) class, however, is simply defined as List(Of T).  The Out keyword is not used here, so that class is not covariant.

I'll provide some examples to try to explain why certain assignments such as the one you're describing can't be done.  I see that your question is written in VB, so my apologies for using C#.

Assume that you have the following classes:

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    public abstract void Travel();
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public override void Travel()
    {
        // specific implementation for Car
    }
}

class Plane : Vehicle
{
    public override void Travel()
    {
        // specific implementation for Plane
    }
}
```

You can create a list of cars, which can only contain objects derived from Car:

```
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
```

You can also create a list of planes, which can only contain objects derived from Plane:

```
        List<Plane> planes = new List<Plane>();
```

You can even create a list of Vehicles, which can contain any object derived from Vehicle:

```
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
```

It's legal to add a car to the list of cars, and it's legal to add a plane to the list of planes.  It's also legal to add both a car and a plane to the list of vehicles.  Therefore, all of the following lines of code are valid:

```
        cars.Add(new Car()); // add a car to the list of cars

        planes.Add(new Plane()); // add a plane to the list of planes

        vehicles.Add(new Plane()); // add a plane to the list of vehicles
        vehicles.Add(new Car()); // add a car to the list of vehicles
```

It's not legal to add a car to the list of planes, nor is it legal to add a plane to the list of cars.  The following lines of code won't compile:

```
        cars.Add(new Plane()); // can't add a plane to the list of cars
        planes.Add(new Car()); // can't add a car to the list of planes
```

Therefore, it's not legal to try to bypass this restriction by assigning the list of cars or the list of planes to the vehicles variable:

```
        vehicles = cars; // This is not allowed
        vehicles.Add(new Plane()); // because then you could do this
```

Consider what the two lines of code are saying above.  It's saying that the vehicles variable is actually a `List<Car>` object, which should only contain objects derived from Car.  However, because `List<Vehicle>` contains an Add(Vehicle) method, it would theoretically be possible to add a Plane object to the `List<Car>` collection, which is definitely not correct.

However, it's perfectly valid to assign a list of cars or a list of planes to an `IEnumerable<Vehicle>` variable.

```
        IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehicles = cars;

        foreach (Vehicle vehicle in vehicles)
        {
            vehicle.Travel();
        }
```

The quick explanation here is that the IEnumerable interface doesn't allow you to manipulate the collection.  It is essentially a read-only interface.  The T objects (Vehicles in this case) are only exposed as a return value on the IEnumerable interface's Current property.  There are no methods that take Vehicle objects as input parameters, therefore there is no danger of the collection being modified in an illegal way.

Side Note:  I've always thought that it would make sense for the `IList<T>` interface to be a composite of an `IReadableList<out T>` interface and an `IWritableList<in T>` interface.

Comment: I agree that it would make sense to segregate reading and writing interfaces, though I'd call them `IReadableByIndex<out T>` and `IAppendable<in T>`.  It might be possible to have `List<T>` inherit `IAppendable<in T>` without breaking compatibility (since implementations of `List<T>.Add(T)` would be considered implementations of `IAppendable<T>.Add(T)`.  Unfortunately, there is not at present any way by which implementations of a read-write `List<T>.this[int]` could regarded as implementations of a read-only `IReadableByIndex<T>.this[int]`.

Comment: @supercat Thanks for your comment! I agree with you...I struggled with that at first when the idea occurred to me - at first I was thinking along the lines of "IReadOnlyList", but as you mentioned, it wouldn't be true to call `List<T>` a read-only list. That's when I changed my thinking to just calling the interface IReadableList. It doesn't make any claim that the underlying type is a read-only collection. It just defines the readable portion of the interface so that you can expose a more targeted interface to consumers, if you want.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice: If I were designing the interfaces for list-like objects and were to include `IReadOnlyList<T>`, the semantics would be that the object promises that exposing it to outside code would not allow outside code to modify the list, but does not promise that the list will not be changed by something with a reference to its "guts".  Whether or not I provided that one, I would also provide `IImmutableList<T>`, which would promise to always return the same sequence of items, so that code which wanted to memoize the contents could do so without making a defensive copy.

Comment: @supercat Yes, I agree. That's why I purposely did not call the interface "IReadOnlyList", but "IReadableList", and the documentation for the interface should clearly indicate that the interface does not imply any read-only semantics.  I'll update this answer sometime this evening to try to explain what I had in mind.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice: I find it unfortunate that Microsoft has persistently failed to provide a means or convention by which collections can indicate whether they encapsulate state which will never be mutatated, state which they can mutate, or a read-only attachment to state which someone else might be able to mutate.  Absent such means, programmers are stuck either making many redundant defensive copies of information, or exposing themselves to bugs when objects whose state was encapsulated by reference turn out to be more mutable than expected.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice: Returning to my original point, I don't dislike `IReadableList<T>` as an interface name; it's certainly better than `IReadOnlyList<T>` for describing something which, if cast to its actual type, might potentially allow read-write access.  My main point was to contrast with `IAppendable<in T>` (which would probably be the most broadly-useful contravariant interface).

Comment: @supercat Ah, I get your point. I agree with you that an IAppendable interface with an `Add(T item)` method would definitely make sense. It seems like the logical complement of `IEnumerable<out T>`.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to think about what you could do with your `List(Of SomeClass)` after you've assigned it to a `List(Of ISomeInterface)` variable.

You could add any object which implements `ISomeInterface` to it, e.g. `SomeOtherClass`, and no longer have a valid `List(Of SomeClass)`

This is the reason that covariance is not defined for `List(Of T)` in this case