# List of interface as function arg

Tags: c#

Here is a sample code :

```
class Program
{
    public class A : I {
        string a = "myClassA";
        // whatever
    }

    public class B : I
    {
        string b = "myClassB";
        // whatever
    }

    public interface I
    {
        // whatever
    }

    public static void myFunction<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[0].GetType().Name); // OUTPUT : A
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list[0])); // OUTPUT : {}
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<I> myList = new List<I>();
        myList.Add(new A());
        myFunction(myList); // arguments mismatch ERROR
    }
}
```

I need this function to output a JSON with appropriate fields (here it should be `{"a":"myClassA"}`

How should I do ?

---

## EDIT

My real context :

```
List<string> JSONElements = new List<string>();
List<I> myList = null;
getDataInList(ref myList);
listToJSON(myList, ref JSONElements);

// ...

public void getDataInList(ref List<I> theList) {
    // insert data in list
    // every elements will be A or every elements will be B
}

// ...

public void listToJSON(List<I> myList, ref List<string> JSONElements) {
     foreach (var element in myList) {
         // I want every field to be included
         // interface has no fields
         JSONElements.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element));
     }
}
```

This function "listToJSON" wont serialize correctly (every elements will be `{}`)

How can I fix this ?

Comment: What would happen if your function adds a `new B()` to that list?

Comment: in the first case you need to cast it to ``List<I>`` before passing to method

Comment: Here's the documentation on Covariance in C#.  In short, List<> isn't covariant so you can't just cast List<A> to List<I> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565732/covariance-contravariance-with-list-vs-ienumerable contains explanation of your current problem, more info can be found using that search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+list+interface+covariant. You need to clarify what you want `myFunction` to do to narrow option - `IEnumerable<I>` is quite common solution in this case.

Comment: Thanks for ressources, I'm gonna check it. I've updated my post with my real context

Comment: I remove my first block of code as it was misleading people about my real question. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you keep

```
public void myFunction(List<I> list)
```

(as `I` not `T`) and then change

```
List<A> myList = new List<A>();
```

to

```
List<I> myList = new List<I>();
```

?

---

In reply to your edit following is printed out by the code at the bottom:

> {"Word":"hello","Number":1} 
>   {"Word":"goodbye","Number":2} 
>   Done, press any key...

I am using Newtonsoft.JSon version 6.0.0.0 from the NuGet feed at https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.

*However*, when I change `public string Word { get; set; }` to `string Word { get { return "Hello"; } }` then `Word` is not serialised. I don't know how the newtonsoft JSON serialiser works "under the hood", but I imagine that if the field is private then it might have more difficulty (de)serialising it.

```
public class Program
{
    public class A : I
    {
        public string Word { get; set; }

        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    public interface I
    {
        int Number { get; set; }
    }

    public static void listToJSON(List<I> myList, ref List<string> JSONElements)
    {
        foreach (var element in myList) {
            JSONElements.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(element));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<I> myList = new List<I>();
        myList.Add(new A { Word = "hello", Number = 1});
        myList.Add(new A { Word = "goodbye", Number = 2});
        List<string> jsonElements = new List<string>();
        listToJSON(myList, ref jsonElements);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", jsonElements));

        Console.WriteLine("Done, press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, but I am going to rephrase my question, it's not that easy

Comment: I think it will work fine. As long as you pass in types of A and B you will still get the proper class names.

Comment: I think my real problem was with Newtonsoft. Thank for pointing this out !

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is best demonstrated by

```
public void myFunction(List<I> list) 
{
        list.Add(new B());
}
```